# Location of island "Trinidad"?

Tags: features, topography, search, trinidad-tobago

I was reading a travel diary of an ancestor of mine who describes a cruise from Hamburg to Natal (South Africa) in 1860. At one point a rock island named Trinidad (supposedly only inhabited by animals) is mentioned in the text and I am curious about its location to trace the route of the ship as exactly as possible.

Does anybody know how to find this out? Since according to the text the ship is heading to the "cap" in a straight way four days later the island could be somewhat close to the coast of western South Africa but might also be further to the north - but probably still close to the African shore.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a cruise to [Natal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natal,_Rio_Grande_do_Norte) in South America?  There is an island called "[Rock Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Island_(Trinidad_and_Tobago))" off the coast of Trinidad (Trinidad and Tobago).

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The text speaks about "Port Natal", mentions "entering the Indian Ocean" shortly upon arrival and talks about "black people" in Natal.

Comment: Also the name of the ship "Candace" is explicitly mentioned which was owned by the German "Hermannsburg Mission" at the time to transport people and goods to their missionary stations in South Africa.

Comment: Port Natal is now called Durban and a little research shows the Candace was headed for Ethiopia but the mission stopped at Durban instead (the Suez Canal was still being built - so they went round the Cape).  There are a lot of Islands off Africa and names can change or even be mis-reported (e.g. Trinidad is Spanish for Trinity - so that could be another option).  If it takes four days to reach the Cape, rock island could be quite a long way north on the West coast of Africa (probably south of the Equator).  You could email the seminary in case they can provide more information (ships logs)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I know all this (the first cruise actually went all the way to Sansibar but wasn't allowed to land there and hence went back to South Africa). I just thought the island might be known to someone or that somebody could provide me with some searching facility for (historical) island names. 

Asking the mission for ship logs would definitely be interesting but the whole thing is not important enough to me to justify the effort involved.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be about Geography rather than GIS